# Send valid email from distributed shared host SMTP servers

Tags: smtp, shared-hosting

I have a web app that as it grows, then number of emails sent per hour could exceed my shared webhost's limit.  I know how to send emails from other SMTP servers, however some mail recipients mark my messages as spam if they are not sent from the server with the same DNS. Ex:  email from admin@myapp.com is accepted when coming from the mail.myapp.com smtp server however admin@myapp.com is sent to spam when coming from mail.sharedhost2.com.  I have not implemented DKIM yet, maybe that is the solution?  Of course we could change our servers to get rid of the email limitation, however we are trying to keep costs down for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe myapp.com has an SPF record which designates mail.myapp.com as the only valid sender. Or some users of mail.sharedhost2.com sends mails which are frequently marked as spam, so your mails, which come from the same IP address, are also affected.

First of all check the trace headers (Received, Received-SPF etc.) of your emails as they are received by the services which moves them to the spam folder. Second check your existing setup, using nslookup:

```
nslookup -type=txt myapp.com
nslookup -type=spf myapp.com
```

For a quick summary about SPF see [SPF Record Syntax](http://www.openspf.net/SPF_Record_Syntax)

Comment: Does SPF override other items such as DKIM?  Is there a resource that you could refer me to regarding adding a second server to the SPF record?

Comment: No, SPF protects the reverse path in the mail envelope. It prevents backscatter spam. It is completely unrelated to DKIM, which protects the message headers.

Comment: Regarding the updating of SPF records, see the link in my updated answer.